# More tables with the same clustered index, can I omit the PK index on the satellite table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have multiple tables storing call data, and they have the same clustered index: start_time (DATETIME). The base table is "calls", and I have a "calls_participants" and a "calls_other_data". All tables also have a call_id CHAR(36) column which identifies a call, so it should be indexed of course.

I am going to store a lot of rows (1 billion) and would like to save space and maintenance costs if possible, so my idea is to index the call_id column only on the base table, and so the other tables would not have any index apart from the CLUSTERED start_time index.
Then if I would have to access a row in the calls_other_data table based on the call_id, I would write something like this:

```
SELECT cod.some_column
FROM calls_other_data cod
WHERE cod.start_time = (SELECT start_time 
                        FROM calls 
                        WHERE call_id = '36-chars-unique-value')
  AND cod.call_id = '36-chars-unique-value'
```

I would say the performance of this query is quite the same as if there was an index on calls_other_data.call_id, since the `calls.call_id` index can be used the same way: the `start_time` value is included automatically, so the same steps have to be performed by SQL Server:

1. Index seek on `(either table).call_id` to get the `start_time`
2. Clustered index seek on `calls_other_data.start_time`

I just never read about such design and would like to read other people's opinion about it :) Are you aware of any drawbacks?

Obviously, if a row is missing from the calls table, then it will be hard to look for it in the other tables, but that I do not mind.

Thanks :)

Comment: This seems dangerous.  What if two calls start at the same time?  I think a unique identifier for a call is more useful than `start_time` being shared across the tables.

Comment: Presumably though your start_time is not *unique* so this would not be a good key

Comment: That is why I am going to filter for both the start_time AND the call_id.

Comment: This might be better suited for Code Review Stack Exchange, since it offers a solution and solicits opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to get at. `calls_other_data` would still carry both a `call_id` column and a `start_time` column, just like the `calls` table, but the `calls_other_date.call_id` column would not be indexed, because indexes come with a storage cost. That seems to be your thinking.

Something to note here is that since your clustered index is not unique on any of your tables, sql will *make* it unique by adding some additional data called a [uniqueifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177484(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). So you already have extra storage here that you may not have considered, making your attempts to "optimize" storage somewhat moot.

I would advise against the approach. Storage is cheap, unique indexes are of great help to the optimizer, and indexes on foreign key columns (or foreign-key-like columns, if you don't actually have any referential integrity) are a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Let me note that the addidional uniqueidentifier will only be added in case of collisions.
But for the sake of uniqueness, I will consider adding the call_id to the clustered index as the second column. Thanks :)